# Ajax request to different endpoints based on position in jsTree

Tags: javascript, jstree

The following tree will be created using https://www.jstree.com/, and the **bold** nodes represent nodes when click will initiate an ajax request and be populated with children.

The ajax requests, however, will have different endpoints based on the type of node (i.e. parentNode, arrayList, or subNode) clicked.  How can one utilize different url endpoints based for different jsTree nodes?

- **parentNode1**
- **parentNode2**
- **parentNode3**

  - property3.1
  - property3.2
  - property3.3
  - **arrayList3**

    - subNodeProperty3.3.1
    - subNodeProperty3.3.2
    - subNodeProperty3.3.3
    - **subNode3.3**

      - subSubNodeProperty3.3.1
      - subSubNodeProperty3.3.2
      - subSubNodeProperty3.3.3

I am thinking of something like the following, but before proceeding, would like to know if I am going down the right path or not.

```
$('#object-browser').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'data' : function (node, cb) {
            switch(node.parents.length) {
                case 0:
                    var url='/nodes/parentNodes';
                    break;
                case 1:
                    var url='/nodes/arrayList';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    var url='/nodes/subNodes';
                    break;
                default:
                    throw 'Node depth of '+node.parents.length+' is not supported';
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    cb(response)
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, status, err) {
                    console.log(jqXHR, status, err)
                }
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: In my opinion this would be the right approach to do it with jstree. In case of a unknown case or ajax failure, I guess you could pass an empty array to the callback

Comment: @StephenS  Okay, thanks.  I thought this would be a fairly common need and therefore a more baked in solution, but it will meet my needs.